# <svg>Code</svg> doesn't work on Safari mobile

Tags: mobile, vector, svg

I've got a problem with an SVG image.

The following code works in all browser but not in safari mobile.
(I use IOS Simulator).

Do you know why? I've not find a solution because all other images I've seen works with the same syntax.

```
    <svg version="1.1" id="logo" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="150px" height="125px" viewBox="0 0 150 125" enable-background="new 0 0 150 125" xml:space="preserve">
<path fill="none" stroke="#E26161" d="M1.295,1"/>
<path fill="none" stroke="#E26161" d="M1.295,125"/>
<path fill="none" stroke="#000000" d="M-9.681-16.75"/>
<path fill="none" stroke="#000000" d="M93.751,21.722"/>
<path fill="none" stroke="#000000" d="M151.887,123.541"/>
<path fill="none" stroke="#000000" d="M77.072,62.437"/>
<path fill="none" stroke="#000000" d="M2.328,1.391"/>
<path fill="none" stroke="#E26161" d="M77.072,62.437"/>
<path fill="none" stroke="#E26161" d="M1.295,0.667"/>
<line fill="none" stroke="#E26161" x1="149.043" y1="125" x2="149.043" y2="0"/>
<line fill="none" stroke="#E26161" x1="75.022" y1="62.5" x2="149.043" y2="0"/>
<line fill="none" stroke="#111111" x1="1" y1="124.938" x2="75.022" y2="62.437"/>
<line fill="none" stroke="#E26161" x1="1" y1="0" x2="75.28" y2="62.906"/>
<line fill="none" stroke="#E26161" x1="1" y1="125" x2="1" y2="0"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have an invisible `U+200B` character at the end of your closing `</svg>`. Remove it and it should work.